# Get heap dump file after pod is completed

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes

I have a pod running a kotlin binary which uses `XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. When the pod becomes OOMKilled, i am no longer able to `kubectl exec` to access that heap dump file. Is there any option to make the pod available for longer?

Comment: You could mount a volume and create the heapdump in there..? Or use a custom start scripts that executes some actions after the application stopped.

Comment: Thanks @dan1stiscrying! Will this stop the pod going to `completed` state? As when I use `kubectl exec`, the error says can't `exec` on completed pod.

Comment: Volumes won't stop it from completing. If you make a script that just sleeps after an OOM error, it won't complete.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a Persistent Volume (PV) and Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) is an ideal setup to retain your data even if your pods are terminated. Here is a document for reference and guidance. [1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/